# Optimal value for multiple input

Tags: regression, optimization, least-squares, experiment-design, algorithms

I run an experiment in which every second I record values of area, circularity, and elongation (there will be probably more variables in the future).

I want to find in which second there are the most optimal values. For example, I am interested in the smallest area, circularity closest to value of 1.0 and elongation also close to the value 1.0.

Could you suggest any methods to solve this?

[image: Sample values]

Comment: Have you considered looking for the time at which the quantity $\text{Area}^2 + (\text{Circularity}-1)^2 + (\text{Elongation}-1)^2$ is minimum?

Comment: Thank you! It is a good point to start. But the values of circularity and elongation will have small effect on the result. Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: You could divide the Area by a scalar, which is going to change the result